# The meaning of "finish out"

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

> It would be better if you finish out the term at least.

What does *finish out* mean? Can I just remove *out* and say *finish the term*? What is the difference between the *finish* and *finish out*?

Comment: What's the context? What does "**term**" refer to?

Comment: @SovereignSun I saw this phrase when I did a listening practice. I googled the difference betwen the word and phrase but no answer. I don't have the text. I just take it as an example for asking the question since it is a simple sentence. "term" in this sentence, I think, is like a period of time.

Comment: @SovereignSun , I assume, from experience, that "term" refers to a school semester, or something similar. This is a common sort of thing to say to a university student who is thinking of taking time off. In the middle of the semester, if they suggest they might leave for a while, a friend or adviser might say, "It would be better if you finish out the term," i.e., don't leave now, but wait until after the current classes are complete.

Answer (score 3):

To "finish out" means to finish, but it is only used in certain contexts, with certain tasks. If I begin a meal, I would never talk about "finishing out" the food I'm eating, but if I were undertaking a military tour of duty, I would naturally refer to "finishing out" my service.

The idea is that, if I undertake certain tasks, I think of myself as "inside" the task until I complete it. When I finish the task, in these cases, I also emerge from the state of being "inside". Thus, just as you can can "walk out" of a building, you can "finish out" a large undertaking.

What type of task do I consider myself "inside" of? Only very large ones, that involve an entire way of life* devoted to the thing I'm doing. Building a model train is a task that I can stand outside of, and work on, or walk away from, as I see fit. Joining a religious mission trip, on the other hand, is immersive, as it entails changing where I live, whom I interact with, and most if not all of my daily activities. Thus, I would "finish" a model train, but I would "finish out" a mission.

*Maybe not an entire way of life. Lifestyle changes, in most cases. An "immersive" task.

Comment: I like this answer, but it may overstate things slightly to say that it must involve an entire way of life. But only slightly. You can finish out a big project at work, and that is not your *entire* way of life, but it would constitute your way of life in the workday.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair. For some people, a semester of university study doesn't even involve an entire way of life. Tour of duty, on the other hand, probably does, lol.

Answer (score 0):

It is known as a *grammar particle* that actually [does not have its own lexical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle).

So, you can definitely say or write ...

> *....finish the term at least.*

Words like 'up' and 'out' are *adverbial particles*.

Answer (score 0):

The cited usage is one where preference has shifted significantly in recent decades...
[image]

...where the vast majority of hits for *both* expressions will be for the same sense [*(to remain or endure until the end of)*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/see-out). If you toggle between BrE/AmE corpuses on [the above NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finish%20out%20the%2Csee%20out%20the&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfinish%20out%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csee%20out%20the%3B%2Cc0) you'll see that the shift occurred earlier in BrE, but the strong preference for ***see out*** is now common to both.

Note that ***finish out / off / up*** can all be used with this sense<sup>1</sup>, but ***see up*** isn't idiomatic at all, and ***see off*** has [completely different meanings](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/see-off) *(repel / drive away* or *accompany someone to a departure point and say goodbye there)*.

---

<sup>1</sup> But note that ***finish off*** and ***finish up*** can also be used with the closely-related sense of ***cause*** something to be gone / finished (for example, by *eating* it). This meaning also occurs with ***see off*** in colloquial contexts...

> *He was so hungry he **finished up / finished off / saw off** his meal before I had even started.*

In practice, I think the preposition *(**out / off / up**)* is always effectively "optional" after ***finish***, so there's a case to be made for saying that if you *do* include it, the effect is one of "emphasis" rather than conveying any specific meaning which might not otherwise have been intended or understood. So from the average learner's perspective, I think the best advice is to note how those prepositions work with ***see*** (where they're *not* optional), but just ignore them with ***finish***, as they don't mean much.